# `ls` Attemptes to list nonexisting symbolic links on WSL

Tags: windows, symlink, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have clean installed windows 10 (build 1803). I have installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store and enabled Linux subsystem. I have done this several times in the past, and never have I had the following issue: my `c` directory is all messed up thanks to symbolic links. Take for example the output of `dir` in `cmd` and `ls` in WSL:

```
C:\Users\username>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC00-A6D5

 Directory of C:\Users\username
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          .
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          3D Objects
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Contacts
05/25/2018  01:19 AM    <DIR>          Desktop
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Documents
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Downloads
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Favorites
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Links
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Music
05/25/2018  12:06 AM    <DIR>          OneDrive
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Pictures
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Saved Games
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Searches
05/25/2018  12:01 AM    <DIR>          Videos
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              15 Dir(s)  88,018,132,992 bytes free
```

---

```
name:/mnt/c/Users/username$ ls
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Application Data': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Cookies': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Local Settings': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'My Documents': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'NetHood': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'PrintHood': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Recent': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'SendTo': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Start Menu': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Templates': Permission denied
3D Objects            NTUSER.DAT{c9e9d809-5fd7-11e8-a0cd-4e0bbe2b78ad}.TM.blf
AppData               NTUSER.DAT{c9e9d809-5fd7-11e8-a0cd-4e0bbe2b78ad}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
Application Data      NTUSER.DAT{c9e9d809-5fd7-11e8-a0cd-4e0bbe2b78ad}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
Contacts              ntuser.dat.LOG1
Cookies               ntuser.dat.LOG2
[...]
```

Comparing the same directory--Ubuntu on the left and cmd on the right--you see that `ls` attempts to list symbolic links that aren't there! I have never had this issue and I have not altered any permissions or anything, so I have no idea what's happening. Can anyone help me with this?

**Here is some possibly useful information:**

Mount gives

```
mount
rootfs on / type lxfs (rw,noatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,gid=5,mode=620)
none on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noatime)
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Then,

```
id -u
1000
id -g
1000
```

My `/etc/wsl.conf` file was non-existent at first, so I created one; but, I don't think this is the key to solving the issue, since `mount` has shown that `c` is correctly mounted. Right now it's this

```
[automount]
enabled = true
```

**My question in short:** there seems to be NO `symlinks` in my directories as confirmed from running `dir` in cmd. Yet, the Ubuntu command line shows symbolic links. Why is that? Oh, also, I cannot delete them (even with `sudo rm`) as permission is denied. This is sort of annoying!

Comment: This isn't really a Unix and Linux problem, as you can see.

Comment: Yes, not directly. But I'm desperate to fix this and I've already posted on superuser and askUbuntu. Also, I used the windows tags so those who know WSL will see it. I don't think I've posted an irrelevant question.

Comment: Multi-posting across several sites (https://superuser.com/questions/1325694/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040022/) is a reason for question closure on this WWW site.  See also https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/

Comment: Ok thank you. I keep that in mind. I would appreciate if you didn't close my questions because someone might be able to help.

Comment: This just started happening to me ( July 2019 ), no idea why, I did update one of my other WSLs to Debian Buster and my Ubuntu WSL installs started yelling about this. Yikes.

Answer (score 3):

> as confirmed from running `dir` in cmd.

This did not confirm anything of the sort.  Use the `/a` option to the `dir` command.  How to use the `dir` command on a non-Unix non-Linux operating system is really beyond the scope of this WWW site.  So I'll stop here after pointing out that this fundamental premise of the question is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You are correct. The `symlinks` are there. Can you help me understand why `ls` is showing them now? I've never had this happen before, and to the best of my knowledge I have not changed any settings.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that if you use:

```
ls --color=tty
```

in the directory /mnt/c, you'll get these error messages:

```
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Documents and Settings': Permission denied                                               
ls: cannot access 'hiberfil.sys': Permission denied                                                                     
ls: cannot access 'pagefile.sys': Permission denied                                                                     
ls: cannot access 'swapfile.sys': Permission denied
```

but if you use simply `/bin/ls` without any arguments, you'll get a clean directory listing. So there's something about this command's attempting to colorize the types of files in the directory that triggers these error messages.

If you redirect stderr to /dev/null, this also inhibits the error messages:

```
alias ls='ls --color=tty 2>/dev/null'
```

Not always advisable, but it does clean up the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but wanted to comment anyway. It looks like the problem here is that `ls --color=tty` tries to access the symbolic link to decide what color to use, but the link is inaccessible in Windows. I am OK with ignoring such errors but I want to see other errors generated by `ls` so simply doing `alias ls='ls --color=tty 2>/dev/null'` isn't going to cut it. Instead, I suggest this alias: `alias ls="ls --color=tty 2> >(grep -v 'ls: cannot read symbolic link.*Permission denied')"` This searches stderr for the error in question and filters it out.

Hope this saves folks some frustration.